# I want to manage multiple servers with 1 external address

Tags: reverse-proxy

**

1. My domain : xxx.com 
    My External ip: 88.101.10.30 WAN ADRESS

    DNS A RECORD 
    A record server1.xxx.com 88.101.10.30 
   A record server2.xxx.com 88.101.10.30 
    A record server3.xxx.com
   88.101.10.30 . 
    . 
    . 
    . 
    MY INTERNAL LAN SERVER ADRESS 
    Machine Name: server1 , ip: 192.168.1.10 
    Machine
   Name: server2 , ip: 192.168.1.20 
    Machine Name: server3 , ip:
   192.168.1.30 
    . 
    . 
    . 
    I want to open all ports to all machines on all protocol basis 
    
    RDP PROTOKOL 
   server1.xxx.com:3389 => 192.168.1.10:3389 App: RDP Server 
   server2.xxx.com:3389 => 192.168.1.20:3389 App: RDP Server 
   server3.xxx.com:3389 => 192.168.1.30:3389 App: RDP Server 
    .

    . 
    . 
    VPN PROTOKOL 
    server1.xxx.com:1194 =>
   192.168.1.10:1194 App: VPN SERVER 
    server2.xxx.com:1194 => 192.168.1.20:1194 App: VPN SERVER 
    server3.xxx.com:1194 => 192.168.1.30:1194 App: VPN SERVER 
    . 
    . 
    . 
    HTTP/HTTPS 
    server1.xxx.com:80|443 => 192.168.1.10:80|443 App:
   Web Application 
    server2.xxx.com:80|443 => 192.168.1.20:80|443
   App: Web Application 
    server3.xxx.com:80|443 =>
   192.168.1.30:80|443 App: Web Application 
    . 
    . 
    . 
    OTHER TCP/UDP PROTOKOL 
    server1.xxx.com:PORT =>
   192.168.1.10:PORT App: ANY 
    server2.xxx.com:PORT => 192.168.1.20:PORT App: ANY 
    server3.xxx.com:PORT => 192.168.1.30:PORT App: ANY 
    . 
    . 
    . 
    I can't do this with reverse proxy because it only provides a protocol based on
   Http and only provides processing for 1 port, I want to be able to
   receive all ports and all protocols.

**

Comment: AFAIK only HTTP/S supports the concept of "virtual hosts" because it's built into the protocol. Other protocols (possibly with exceptions) simply bind to an IP address and can't be forwarded to a different host based only on a host name. The protocol simply does not support this as it can't "see" the host name that is being addressed. You need either separate external IP addresses or separate ports.

Comment: You really need to learn networking basics first. Not only it is impossible to have what you ask, it demonstrates your gross lack of knowledge and understanding.

Comment: What one typically would do in this situation, is run a VPN server accessible from outside of your intranet, and then connect to a OpenSSH server.  This would allow you to connect to multiple servers, using their host name, without directly making ever server directly accessible from the internet. Making ever service on your network directly accessible is a horrible idea

Answer (score 2):

You think too much in terms of host names, while Internet is running based on IP and IPv6. Names are only auxiliary thing, designed to allow easier access for us humble human beings. For the service to be independent, it has to have a dedicated IP/IPv6 address.

Only HTTP was extended somewhat to give host names extended meaning. Absolutely any other protocol only gives meaning to addresses and ports. Also NAT appeared that allows several hosts to hide behind a single address; previously if you wanted the host to communicate with the Internet you had to assign some globally unique routed (public) address to it.

Consequently, you can't rely on names so much, and you **absolutely** have to use different IP addresses and/or ports to direct traffic to different services. You can't distinguish anything just by names.

---

For HTTP **only**, it is possible to run name-based reverse proxy (any will do: Nginx, Caddy, Haproxy, Apache), so all websites will be available without the need to specify port names. However, for HTTPS, you'll terminate the TLS layer on the reverse proxy, therefore you'll need to have all the globally trusted certificates and their corresponding private keys on the reverse proxy, it's natural to run it on the front end node. (With Haproxy it might be possible to also analyse the ALPN and SNI in the ClientHello and directly pass HTTPS traffic to back end servers based on name, but that's really advanced topic.)

For all other protocols the best you have is this:

```
TCP 88.101.10.30:3389 -> 192.168.1.10:3389
TCP 88.101.10.30:3390 -> 192.168.1.20:3389
TCP 88.101.10.30:3391 -> 192.168.1.30:3389
```

and so on. Notice different ports are mapped to different servers. Basically there is **no way to go around** this.

While each of those servers can run its own VPN service, it might be better to run a single service on the front end system and provide different access (different firewall rules) to different back end servers for different clients, based on client certificate DNs. This way, after connecting to the VPN, each of them will see and use internal server addresses (192.168.1.x) directly without any NAT.

Also, for the SSH access you may employ SSH Jump Host configuration so it'll *appear* to the users as if they connect to the internal servers directly. For that, you create a limited user on the front end node. Each user generates a SSH key and you install these keys as usual on the back end nodes. Additionally, you install this key to the front end system into that limited user's authorized_keys, and further limit it to only permit that connection for TCP port forwarding. The users then configure their SSH clients to automatically use public IP as a jump host when connecting to the back end systemd (using e.g. ProxyJump option).

---

I'd like to also incorporate @davidgo suggestion: change IP addressing away from 192.168.1.x, because it is configured on many SOHO devices by default (also, don't use 192.168.0.x, 192.168.88.x, and so on). It'll make many problems in the future much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you have asked in the way you have asked this (particularly the "Other TCP/UDP PROTOKOL" requirement)

You can do this by setting up a single VPN endpoint (or multiple VPN's on multiple ports) and then connecting to the VPN - if you push the routes your VPN client will be able to reach all the IP's and ports behind it.   It would be a good idea to renumber to something outside 192.168.1 - in fact, renumbering to 172.18.x.x would make it a lot less likely for you to have collissions with the IP assigned to you remotely.